# Power BI Report Builder - Export to Word not extending to width

Tags: powerbi, reportbuilder

I have a user in Power BI Report Builder that is needing to export their published report to Word and PDF.  It exports to PDF just fine and formats to fit, but doesn't extend to fit in a word document.

[Example of Word doc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVdFz.png)

I've suggested the margins might be in play and told them to adjust so that it fits within a letter format.  I'm new to Power BI Report Builder so I'm looking for suggestions or other resources in helping me understand.